# Embedding a webpage into an Exchange Outlook email? iframe

Tags: iframe, format, exchange-server, html

I've got a webpage with just text and some formatting that I'd like to embed into an Exchange email.

Can I format an iFrame in an email to Exchange users?

I've tried something like this with no luck from a webmail exchange client.

Answer (score 4):

Using iframes in email doesnt work in practice because it is great security risk, hence all iframes etc are blocked by anti-spams and email clients.

Consider embedding a link - still - it is also threat, and sometimes it can be blocked more often then message without links.

The best is to make both text and html version, embed links in both, this gives the higher chance of getting thru.